# Unable to display Mesh as an interactive marker

Tags: ros, stl, markers, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use a mesh as a marker.
To do that, I changed [basic_controls.py](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/blob/indigo-devel/interactive_marker_tutorials/scripts/basic_controls.py) to :

```
marker.type = Marker.MESH_RESOURCE;
marker.mesh_resource = 'package://HexagonalPrism.STL'
```

(And added a `from visualization_msgs.msg import *` at the top as well)

I get the following error

```
Error retrieving file [package://HexagonalPrism.STL]: Could not parse package:// format into file:// format
```

RViz screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-PFIKJ4nKIuMVdzd3AtekNXYUk/view?usp=sharing

The same works fine if I do a simple marker:

```
marker = visualization_msgs.msg.Marker()
marker.type = visualization_msgs.msg.Marker.MESH_RESOURCE
marker.mesh_resource = 'package://HexagonalPrism.STL'
```

RViz : screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-PFIKJ4nKIuaXJna1ZocXNwdnM/view?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212787/unable-to-display-mesh-as-an-interactive-marker/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file format is `'package://' + name_of_package + '/' + filename_in_package`

For example, if you have HexagonalPrism.STL in the package hexbot, the syntax should be `'package://hexbot/HexagonalPrism.STL'`. If its in a folder called meshes in that package, `'package://hexbot/meshes/HexagonalPrism.STL'`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2015-07-05**:
Thanks for the quick help. But it still doesn't work.
Here's the code. Just minor changes from the visualization_tutorials

https://github.com/madratman/visualization_tutorials/commit/ccb96cc5098be1893c22237653090b192f13abac

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-07-05**:
You have to be more specific than "doesn't work"

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2015-07-05**:
Oh sorry, I don't get the error I wrote in the question, but RViz still looks like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-PFIKJ4nKIuMVdzd3AtekNXYUk/view

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-07-05**:
Check the filenames carefully, especially dae vs stl.

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2015-07-05**:
There are both dae and stl files here. https://github.com/madratman/visualization_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/interactive_marker_tutorials_local/meshes
I tried stl as well. No change. :\